# Azure File Share refuses file deletion

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-account

I've tried removing a file in an Azure File Share using

- the `az` CLI
- Azure Storage Explorer

Both yield the error:
`The specified resource may be in use by an SMB client.` and `ErrorCode:SharingViolation`

I've tried listing file handles with the Azure Powershell and `az` CLI commands, but no file handles are shown. Supposedly, this should reveal any file locks.
I've also tried rebooting everything (that I know of!) that is connected to this file share. Other files in the same directory can be deleted. Everything else with this file share seems normal.

Any idea how I can find the source of the lock, and how to delete it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check any other client accessing the share?
Create another test file in the same storage account(fileshare) for testing purpose and see are facing the similar  issue?

Sharingviolation: The operation failed because the object is already opened and does not allow the sharing mode that the caller requested.

Based on the error message you may refer to this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/managing-file-locks
which provides detailed information on file locks

Try to [Unlock all Azure file share locks](https://serverfault.com/questions/929586/unlock-all-azure-file-share-locks)

This article lists common problems that are related to Microsoft Azure Files when you connect from Windows clients. It also provides possible causes and resolutions for these problems. In addition to the troubleshooting steps in this article: [Unable to delete files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-troubleshoot-windows-file-connection-problems?tabs=azure-portal)

Comment: Good suggestions, pointing in the right direction. I found the offending file lock using these instructions: https://infra.engineer/azure/65-azure-clearing-the-lock-on-a-file-within-an-azure-file-share